# Finding the derivative of $f(y(x),y'(x),x)$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

For a function: $f(y(x),y'(x),x)$

Is it correct to assume that:

> [image]

If so in the case where function $f(y,y',x)$ does not explicit depend on $x$. we should have:

> [image]

However in my notes it is giving as:

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your first expression.  Did you mean to have four different things all multiplied?  The one in the notes is correct.

Comment: Your notes are right. Where on earth did you get that first formula from?!? (And are the $x$s in the middle supposed to be $\times$ (multiplication signs)?)

Comment: By the way, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write formulas instead of posting images.

Comment: i though when you change one variable the others would stay constant. For example Let $g(x) = f(y(x), b(x))$. Then,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot b(x) + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot \frac{db}{dx} + y(x) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = f(y(x), y'(x), x)$. Then,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\cdot \frac{dy'}{dx} + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot y'(x) + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\cdot y''(x) + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 
$$

Comment: If $g(x) = f(y(x), b(x), x)$. Then would the following be correct

$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot \frac{db}{dx} + 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: yes, this is correct